# Subset sum with unlimited elements

Tags: algorithm, subset-sum

I am trying to solve a coding problem at topcoder for practice. I believe I have solved it partly, but am struggling with the other half.

The essence of the problem is "Given a set P with positive integers, find the smallest set of numbers that adds up to a sum S. You can use an element of the set more than once. There may be a case where the sum is not attainable as well."

For small inputs, the exponential algorithm of searching through all possible subsets works. However, the size of the set can go up to 1024.

What is the idea behind solving this problem? Is this problem even an extension of subset-sum?

[EDIT]

This is the problem on topcoder : https://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=8571

Comment: Probably Dynamic-programming and i'm sure wiki will present this approach for the classic problem (which you might adapt).

Comment: Sorting the set might be helpful.

Comment: @sascha Yes, I was thinking that there might be a DP solution as well. I just wanted to confirm that this is infact an extension of the subset sum problem

Comment: Do you have a link to this problem?

Comment: @0x499602D2 I've added an edit with the link to the topcoder problem

Comment: This seems to be the classic example of Change-making problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem . As @sascha mentioned, this is solved with Dynamic Programming.